# $y'=\sin^4y+\cos^4y , y(0)=1$. Find the maximal domain using Picard-Lindelof (without solving the ode)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

$y'=\sin^4y+\cos^4y , y(0)=1$

I have to find the maximal domain using Picard-Lindelof (without solving the ode).

My solution:

Denote $f(x,y)=\sin^4(y)+\sin^4(y)$.

$f_y=4\sin^3(y)\cos(y)-4\cos^3(y)\sin(y)\leq 8$

Denote $B=\{ (x,y)| |x|\leq a , |y-1| \leq b\}$ as a rectangle.

$f(x,y)=\sin^4(y)+\sin^4(y) \leq \sin^2(y)+\sin^2(y)=1$

Then $M=1$.

The ode has a solution in $I=[-\alpha,\alpha]$ such that $\alpha=\min\{a,\frac{b}{M}\}=\min\{a,b\}$

Then the domain is $\infty < x < \infty$ since $a,b$ can be chosen as bigger as I want ?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The right side being globally bounded is already enough, additionally you computed a global Lipschitz constant. With other equations there is a trade-off, the larger you select $b$ in the proof construction, the smaller $a$ has to be. This is obviously not the case here. // Note that $f_y=-\sin(2y)\cos(2y)=-sin(4y)$ can have an even smaller bound.